# Pick random spot inside array, move items before it to the end

Tags: javascript

I have no idea how to approach this, so i'm asking suggestions/help.

Say i have this array

```
 let availablePositions = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H",];
```

I want to pick a random spot

[image]

Move the items in front of the picked spot to the back

[image]

How could i achieve this?

Comment: Is there *any* aspect of this that you *can* implement?

Comment: Start by researching how to select a random index based on the length of an array. Then look for how to select items in an array until a certain index. From there you'll need to split the array into two arrays and combine them in a new order. Just do some research and you'll get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use `splice` function that is used to remove and insert operations on arrays. [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
let availablePositions = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H",];

// split point
let i = 2;

let deleted = availablePositions.splice(0, i);
let newArray = availablePositions.concat(deleted);
```

Variables:

```
availablePositions = ["C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
deleted = ["A", "B"]
newArray = ["C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "A", "B"]
```

2. `splice` function changes the original array if you want to **keep the original array** you can use `slice` function that creates a shallow copy array [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
let availablePositions = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H",];

// split point
let i = 2;

let deleted = availablePositions.slice(0, i);
let newArray = availablePositions.slice(i).concat(deleted);
```

Variables:

```
availablePositions = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
deleted = ["A", "B"]
newArray = ["C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "A", "B"]
```

Comment: ```deleted``` and ```newArray``` are not declared yet, which would cause an error.

Comment: @TimothyChen No, it would actually declare a global variable

Comment: It would still be better to declare it first though...

Comment: @TimothyChen Yes. Doing it without `var` is usually considered a bad practice.

Comment: @TimothyChen thanks, I have updated the declarations and also added `slice` method

Comment: For some reason this gives me duplicates. Every letter is in there twice. Any ideas?

Comment: @Grapjas I have tested both solutions and you can see on Variables part that what you get after execution.

Comment: I see what i did wrong, the problem was elsewhere. Thanks for the help, works perfectly :)